# Finding the P-values of a 3-way ANOVA in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, statistics, anova, p-value

I'm totally stuck on this.  Is there any way to draw the p-values out of a simulation run multiple times? I've tried the method here https://pythonfordatascience.org/anova-2-way-n-way/

```
pValues = np.zeros(100)

for k in range (99) :
       y = simCorn(overallEffect=10, fertilizerEffect=[1,2,3],rowEffect=[1,0,1], colEffect=[0,1,1]) 
       pValues[k] = ols('Yield ~ C(Fertilizer)+C(Row)+C(Column)', y).fit()
```

But I couldn't even get the base ols function to work, let alone isolate and pull the p-value...

So, I tried the statsmodels method...

```
pValues = np.zeros(100)

for k in range (99) :
       y = simCorn(overallEffect=10, fertilizerEffect=[1,2,3],rowEffect=[1,0,1], colEffect=[0,1,1]) 
       pValues[k] = sm.stats.anova_lm(data=y).Pr(F)
```

...but nothing seems to be working.

Any help here would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: simCorn is not a statsmodels function, see for example https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/interactions_anova.html

Comment: I'm having issues understanding it, since the dataframes/tables they called are imported.  If I made a dataframe with that function, do I need to do something extra to reference the columns?